# How to load from database on page scroll in php and jquery with ajax on the same page

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I need some help concerning my eCommerce site am developing, I want to load carts from database on page scroll the problem having is that i want to pull out my "Filter Categories first" before displaying carts items in the database below is my script

```
<span class="applied-amount">Applied Filters</span>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm clear-all pull-right" id="clear-all">CLEAR ALL</button>
</div>
<div class="column-filters panel-group" id="accordion">
<div class="panel-title-bcrums"> </div>
<!--Category Panel-->
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <div class="panel-title"> CATEGORY </div>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <label name="filter-category" data-category-url="computer-software" data-category-id=""> <span class="filter-key">Computer Software</span> <span class="filter-count">(724)</span> <i class="fa fa-angle-right pull-right caret-icon" name="filter-category" data-category-url="computer-software"></i> </label>
        <label name="filter-category" data-category-url="accessories-computing" data-category-id=""> <span class="filter-key">Computing Accessories</span> <span class="filter-count">(8764)</span> <i class="fa fa-angle-right pull-right caret-icon" name="filter-category" data-category-url="accessories-computing"></i> </label>
        <label name="filter-category" data-category-url="computing-bundles" data-category-id=""> <span class="filter-key">Computing Bundles</span> <span class="filter-count">(3)</span> <i class="fa fa-angle-right pull-right caret-icon" name="filter-category" data-category-url="computing-bundles"></i> </label>
        <label name="filter-category" data-category-url="desktop-monitors" data-category-id=""> <span class="filter-key">Desktop and Monitors</span> <span class="filter-count">(493)</span> <i class="fa fa-angle-right pull-right caret-icon" name="filter-category" data-category-url="desktop-monitors"></i> </label>
        <label name="filter-category" data-category-url="laptops" data-category-id=""> <span class="filter-key">Laptops</span> <span class="filter-count">(2309)</span> <i class="fa fa-angle-right pull-right caret-icon" name="filter-category" data-category-url="laptops"></i> </label>
        <label name="filter-category" data-category-url="networking" data-category-id=""> <span class="filter-key">Networking</span> <span class="filter-count">(1628)</span> <i class="fa fa-angle-right pull-right caret-icon" name="filter-category" data-category-url="networking"></i> </label>
        <label name="filter-category" data-category-url="printers-scanners-5232" data-category-id=""> <span class="filter-key">Printers, Scanners and Accessories</span> <span class="filter-count">(3550)</span> <i class="fa fa-angle-right pull-right caret-icon" name="filter-category" data-category-url="printers-scanners-5232"></i> </label>
        <label name="filter-category" data-category-url="projectors-5233" data-category-id=""> <span class="filter-key">Projectors &amp; Accessories</span> <span class="filter-count">(582)</span> <i class="fa fa-angle-right pull-right caret-icon" name="filter-category" data-category-url="projectors-5233"></i> </label>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
Brand Panel
<div class="panel panel-default ">
<div class="for-brand"></div>
<div class="panel-heading">
    <div class="panel-title" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="true"> BRAND <span class="panel-selected-size -brand">(0)</span> <i class="fa fa-angle-down pull-right caret-icon"></i> <i class="fa fa-angle-up pull-right caret-icon"></i> </div>
</div>
<div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
<input type="text" class="search-brand" id="search-brand-input" placeholder="Search brands..">
<div class="brand-list-remote"></div>
<div id="aggregated_brand" class="brand-list" filter-attr-val="aggregated_brand">
<label data-name="Acer" class="aggregated_brand filter-40660">
    <input class="filter-box" type="checkbox" name="filter-brand"
                                                               data-brand="Acer"  data-count="121"/>
    <span class="filter-key">Acer</span> <span class="filter-count">(121)</span> </label>
<label data-name="Apple" class="aggregated_brand filter-39454">
    <input class="filter-box" type="checkbox" name="filter-brand"
                                                               data-brand="Apple"  data-count="332"/>
    <span class="filter-key">Apple</span> <span class="filter-count">(332)</span> </label>
<label data-name="Asus" class="aggregated_brand filter-150136">
    <input class="filter-box" type="checkbox" name="filter-brand"
                                                               data-brand="Asus"  data-count="104"/>
    <span class="filter-key">Asus</span> <span class="filter-count">(104)</span> </label>
Displaying of carts here from tables
<div class="catalog-box">
    <ul id="myList" class="catalog">
        <?php include('getresult.php'); ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Google it where you can get multiple blogs regarding this http://www.codexworld.com/load-data-on-page-scroll-jquery-ajax-php-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$(window).scroll()` to achieve the task...

```
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    yourFunction();
});
function yourFunction(){
   //call your ajax here
}
```

In your ajax write a code to get the data from database and on it's success load your next part of html.